# Ensemble Techniques for multilabel data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-modeling

I observed that [Adaboost](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.fit) or [Bagging](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html) ensemble classifiers present in sklearn only work for single label training data. How do I use these for multilabel data?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the Adaboost or VotingClassifier doesn't work for multilabel classification data. We get a NotImplementedError. I believe they are working towards it and might be out in next version or so.